# OnPageScroll in GridViewPager (Android Wear)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, wear-os

I am using GridViewPager in Android Wear app and I want to detect onPageScrolled or OnTouch, something that would enable me to check on which page the user is so I can run the appropriate code. In Android, there's viewpager and it has those methods, but apparentely not the GridViewPager in Android Wear.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

GridViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As Simple As This >>>

```
 GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager2);
 pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPageScrolled(int i, int i1, float v, float v1, int i2, int i3) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int i, int i1) {
          //Get Selected Fragment
          adapter.getFragment(i,i1)
     }

     @Override
     public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

     }
 });
```